# C++ RayTracer: Plane creating two intersections at +y and -y coords

Tags: c++, raytracing

I have my basic Ray Tracer up and running with multiple objects, colour and shading.

When implementing a plane I define a single point on the plane and a normal to the surface. All seems well with the output apart from:

if i define a plane to have a point of (0,-10,0), when i create a shape that goes past the y coord of -10 and 10 (eg. imagine a sphere with centre (0,0,0) and radius 15) i get an intersection and the sphere cuts off at both +10 in y and -10 in y.

I would post an image but i do not have enough reputation :/ i can imgur upload and link if requested.

Now i expect the intersection in -y as that is where the plane is defined, but why is it intersection above too?

Code for intersection check is:

```
bool Plane::intersect(Ray ray){
double test = (ray.GetUnit().DotProduct(this->_NormalUnitVector));
if (test < 0)
    return true;
else if (test == 0 && (ray.GetPoint().GetVar()[2]) == this->_PointOnPlane.GetVar()[2])
    return true;
else
    return false;}

/*ray.GetPoint() returns point on ray.
ray.GetUnit() returns unit vector of ray direction.
GetVar functions returns array of {x,y,z} coords of a 3d vector. (so getVar()[2] returns z coord).*/
```

and the objects passed to this function are:

```
for (int p = 0; p < (int)_planelist.size(); p++){
            bool intersect_plane = _planelist[p].intersect(_viewplane.GetPixelRay(_camera, i, j));
            if (intersect_plane == true){
                Ray reflected = _planelist[p].reflected(_viewplane.GetPixelRay(_camera, i, j));
                _raylist.push_back(reflected);
                _indexlist.push_back(p);
                _objecttype.push_back(0);
            }
        }
```

Where _planelist is a list of plane objects and and the '_viewplane.GetPixelRay(_camera, i, j)' returns the light ray going through each pixel [i,j].

Is my current method for intersection correct?

Comment: You ray-plane intersection does not look correct. See http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall2000/cs426/lectures/raycast/sld017.htm for example.

Comment: My intersection functions tests if the dot product between V and N in the slide you linked is <0, this would mean a positive value for t, and hence and intersection in the positive direction of the ray, right? 
What is it with my test which is wrong that you can see?

Comment: Not necessarily, the sign of t also depends on at what side of the plane the origin of your ray is. Your (N.V) sign condition is applicable for infinite line (and you have actually check t != 0 for the line), but not for the ray.

Comment: I understand what youre saying i think, but if i test for just the condition that (t != 0) my intersection will always return true unless the ray is parallel. How can i get around this problem and test for an intersection in the positive direction no matter which side of the plane the ray origin is?

Comment: That's where that link comes handy :) You have to compute your t as t=-(R.N+d)/(V.N), where R is origin or your ray, and d=-P.N (P is a point you define on your plane: {0,-10,0}). t>0 => ray hits the plane.

Comment: Awesome, got some stuff to work finally! Thanks for that, i was just over simplifying the condition in my mind, totally makes sense now :)